# How to capture CTRL + CTRL key presses in my Win32 application?

Tags: c++, keyboard, shortcut, ctrl, registerhotkey

How would I capture the user pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> twice (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) globally. I want to be able to have my application window hidden and then make it visible when the user invokes it with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key presses similar to Google Quick Search Box. The user may have focus on a different window. I've looked at RegisterHotKey, but that seems to be for `MODIFIERS + character key` unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create such a hotkey, do this:

```
ATOM hotkey = GlobalAddAtom("Your hotkey atom name");
if(hotkey) RegisterHotKey(hwnd, hotkey, MOD_CONTROL, VK_CONTROL);
else { ...error... }
```

And then handle the `WM_HOTKEY` message:

```
case WM_HOTKEY:
    if(wParam == hotkey)
    {
       // CTRL pressed!!!
    }
break;
```

I guess you'll figure out yourself that you need to store whether the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key was pressed before. For example, if it was pressed once in the last 500 ms, and the user presses it again, you have a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd> press.

Comment: Where does key debouncing take place?

Comment: Better to use GetDoubleClickTime (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646258(VS.85).aspx) than hard-code in 500.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews: I don't quite see what you mean, we only need the pressed-down event here, which is `WM_HOTKEY`.

Comment: @Bill: Yes, that's worth considering. Good idea ;)

Comment: What's the difference between these 2 calls?

RegisterHotKey(hwnd, hotkey, MOD_CONTROL, 0); 
RegisterHotKey(hwnd, hotkey, MOD_CONTROL, VK_CONTROL);

From what I've seen, I get repeated WM_HOTKEY message when the Control key is held down or if pressed in combination with another key (e.g. CTRL+space) in the 2nd case. In the 1st case, I only get WM_HOTKEY messages when the control is pressed and released without any other key combination.

Comment: My solution will trigger a message when you press CTRL. If you press another key after that, like together (= CTRL+Space), it will send another message. And of course you get repeated messages when you hold down the CTRL key - just like any other key it gets repeated as defined in the control panel settings for the keyboard.